# Calculus and Integrals Velocity, Acceleration, Displacement

Tags: calculus, integration

A particle moves along a straight line.  Its positions at time $t \ge 0$ ($t$ in seconds) is given in meters.  The acceleration function (in $m/s^2$) of the particle is $a(t) =t^2+ 4t+ 6$ and $s(0) = 0$, $s(1) = 20$.  Find the displacement $s(t)$.

I am confused on how to do this. Any help thank you.

Comment: Integrate acceleration twice to get displacement.

Comment: @Wintermute yea then what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}$$
This can be written as $$\int_0^Tdv=\int_0^T a(t)dt$$
Integrating, you get $$v(T)-v(0)=\int_0^T a(t)dt$$
Do the integration of the right hand side. Then repeat the same procedure for the displacement. Note that you will get a formula that includes integrating twice the acceleration, plus two integration constants: $v(0)$ and $s(0)$. $s(0)$ it is given explicitly to you. $v(0)$ can be obtained from $s(1)$ (just plug in $t=1$ in your displacement equation)

Comment: help please i dont know what to do

Comment: The other answer already has the formula for $s(t)$. If you say $t=0$ in that equation you have $s(0)=c_2$, so $c_2=0$. Calculate $s(t)$ for $t=1$. What do you get?

Comment: his equation is wrong

Comment: never mind i figured it out thanks

Comment: I've fixed the powers in his equation

Answer (score 1):

$$a(t) = \frac{d^2s}{dt^2} = t^2+4t+6$$
Integrating once with respect to $t$ you will get $$v(t) = \frac{t^3}{3}+2t^2+6t+c_1$$

Integrating second time with respect to $t$ you will get $$s(t) = \frac{t^4}{12}+\frac{2t^3}{3}+3t^2+c_1t+c_2$$

What we need now is to solve the initial value problem. The clues are on $s(0)$ and $s(1)$. You have two unknowns and two equations so this is solvable.

Comment: yea how do i do that

Comment: thats the part im confused on

Comment: Plug 0 and 1 at the last equation you have equation in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$

Comment: i still dont get it

Comment: how do i plug em in, what do i use